# What are high throw solutions?

Tags: electrochemistry

I am trying to make a copper sulfate electroplating solution. I came across a [document](http://www2.bren.ucsb.edu/~dturney/port/papers/Modern%20Electroplating/02.pdf) (Schlesinger and Paunovic 2011) which mentions the amount of copper sulfate that should be added to water to create such a solution. In Table 2.1 on the bottom of page 35, it has two columns: one for conventional solutions and one for high throw solutions.

I read another [paper](http://electronics.macdermid.com/documents/resources/Innovative%20High%20Throw%20Copper%20Electrolytic%20Process.pdf) (Nikolova and Watkowski) which talks about high throw copper electroplating process. All I could glean from the paper was that high throw solutions enable higher aspect ratios for copper PCBs.

Please reply if anyone knows what high throw solutions are.

**References:**

Nikolova, Maria, and Jim Watkowski. “INNOVATIVE HIGH THROW COPPER ELECTROPLATING PROCESS FOR METALLIZATION OF PCB.”

Schlesinger, M., and M. Paunovic. 2011. Modern Electroplating. The ECS Series of Texts and Monographs. Wiley. http://books.google.com/books?id=j3OSKTCuO00C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This page](http://www.plating.com/platingtechnical/poorthrowingpower.htm) suggests that throwing power is the ability to coat a surface evenly regardless of current density differences, and thus to produce an even plating thickness across the whole of a surface.

A solution with high throwing power would thus have the ability to produce a good, close-to-uniform coating on more difficult surface shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I googled and learned from a [webpage](http://www.ami.ac.uk/courses/topics/0223_plate/index.html) that "The ability of a solution to plate evenly over a large area (‘covering power’), and to plate into holes (‘throwing power’) depends on the current density, the concentration of acid and copper ions, the agitation of the solution, the anode-to-cathode separation, and the bath additives."

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Could you summarize the source you linked? It helps combat link rot.